# Netbeans IDE - How can I change default run target of ANT script?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I just write ant script and do run it for test and now I complete my script and do test it.

But something annoy me is the default right-click run target is the first target that I chose for test on the first time. And I want to change this to another run target to be default.

How can I do that please help me.

Comment: So, which kind of project do you have -- is it a Netbeans project, or a free-format Ant project (icon is a little pink plane)?

Comment: @coolcfan I think it's free-format Ant which I make from context menu -> New -> Other -> Other (file type) -> Ant Build Script

Comment: OK, I found it. I just add description property on target tag and it appear on context menu when I right-click on the Ant script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `build.xml` in the base dir of your your project.

Change this part:

`<project name="MyProject" default="MyDefaultTarget" basedir=".">`